# How to control if an object should not be created in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to control if an object should not be created in Javascript? I have been searching, and it seems that the only way to not returning this, is returning an object. This does not work:

```
var Example = function( params ) {

    if(!params){
        return null;
    }

};

var foo = new Example(); // foo is not null
```

I don´t want foo to be instanceOf Example.

Thanks, best regards.

Comment: You could throw an exception.

Comment: I don't understand. If you don't want to create an object why are you invoking the new keyword? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The params have to be validated before calling new (or not if the test fails)

Comment: If params are not correct, why would I want an object which does not work? Perhaps the exception is the best way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you're creating an object using your function as a constructor but the return value from a constructor is ignored.

What you can do is make a factory function like so

http://javascript.info/tutorial/factory-constructor-pattern

```
Example = function()
{
    this.Value = 10;   
}

Example.Create = function(params ) { 
    if(!params){
        return null;
    }
    return new Example();
}

var result = Example.Create();
alert(result);
```

jsFiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/3pab7cco/

---

Or you can add a bool value to your function and then check that after you have created your object

```
var Example = function( params ) {
    this.isValid = true;
    if(!params){
        this.isValid = false;;
    }
};

var example = new Example();
if(!example.isValid){ example = null; }
alert(example);
```

Comment: It is a good idea. For each new instance I create, is a new Example.Create instance created too? Thanks.

Comment: I can't see why not, if you follow the first example you will always be return't a null object if no params is passed, however the second example does require you to do an addition check after the constructor has ran